# How can I make a multiline shiny dashboard header title?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am trying to do a multiline dashboard header title, since my title is too long.

The code is:

```
dashboardHeader(title="NMR Reference\nCorrection")
```

[image: Header doesn't show the whole thing]

Answer (score 5):

Figured out.
http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#long-titles

It turned out there's a documentation on it, and it's right at the dashboard website. But anyway I will leave it on the overstack, it might be beneficial.

Thank you so much,
Bill